# A synonym for coldhearted that has a positive connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means being able to act in spite of emotions. It's meaning would be to detached or coldhearted, but with a positive connotation.

Comment: Level-headed, logical, principled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Dispassionate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispassionate)* fits the bill:

> **dispassionate**, *adj.*: :  not influenced by strong feeling; *especially* :  not affected by personal or emotional involvement [a *dispassionate* critic] [a *dispassionate* approach to an issue]

Answer (score 0):

***Cool-headed*** -   Of a person: calm, composed, dispassionate; not easily excited or agitated. Also of a thing or action: characterized by or exhibiting calmness, composure, etc.(OED)